# how to create multiple relation in single modal in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have 3 tables These are

```
1.categories
   id      int(11) Auto Increment    
  categoryname  varchar(35)

2.Products
 id int(11) Auto Increment   
 category_id    int(11)  
 skunumber  varchar(35)  
 image  varchar(255)     
 name   varchar(35)  
 size   varchar(12)  
 stock  int(11)  
 cu_price   decimal(10,0)    
 margincost decimal(10,0)

3.promotionproducts
 id int(11) Auto Increment   
 promotion_id   int(11)  
 product_id int(11)
```

also i have 3 modals and these are

```
class Category extends Model {

//
 public function product() {

    return $this->hasMany('App\Product', 'category_id');
    //return $this->belongsTo('App\Promotion', 'promotion_id');
}


}

class Promotion extends Model {

//
 public function promotionproduct() {

    return $this->hasMany('App\Productoffer', 'promotion_id');
}


}

class Productoffer extends Model {

 protected $table = 'promotionproducts';

//
public function promotion() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Promotion', 'promotion_id');
}

}
```

now i want to relate category or promotion based on category_id . how can i create relation amoung them

Comment: I don't think I understand. Do you want to create another relation? What kind of (one-to-one, many-to-one, ...), from which table to which table and what are the fields that store the foreign keys?

Comment: Have you set the foreign keys?